# Forcing an optional interface property to be defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, option-type

Say I have the following interface:

```
interface Example {
    optionalString?: string
    // ... other props
}
```

And I have a function taking a `Example` as a parameter. I know the return type syntax is bogus.

```
function ensureDefined (example : Example) : Example & {optionalString: string}
```

The idea of this function is to ensure that the property `optionalString` of `example` is defined and that object returned. In which case, every time I wish to access the `optionalString` property, I don't need to do an `if(example.optionalString){}`.

I have tried creating an extension of the interface like so:

```
interface ExampleExtension extends Example {
    optionalString: string // notice no '?'
    // ... other props
}
```

But then this one is not assignable back onto a variable with a type of the base interface.

Am I overcomplicating this? Should I just have two separate variables with two different types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface extension works for me [on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Example%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20optionalString%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%20other%20props%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20ExampleExtension%20extends%20Example%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20optionalString%3A%20string%20%2F%2F%20notice%20no%20'%3F'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%20other%20props%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20ee%3A%20ExampleExtension%3B%0D%0Alet%20e%3A%20Example%20%3D%20ee%3B%0D%0A).  If it still doesn't work for you, please add code sufficient to reproduce the problem to the question.

Comment: Seems like you're right. Not sure what I was doing before!

Comment: Is there any way to extend an interface inline though in this case in the function's return signature?

Comment: The `Example & {optionalString: string}` syntax you originally used is working for me.

Comment: I believe the `&` operator is an intersection and so will work in this case (as it is solely the intersection which is needed). This will only allow properties common to the left and right of the ampersand to be _returned_.

Comment: `&` means an intersection of _types_, not of sets of properties: `A & B` is the type of objects that are of both type `A` and type `B`.  Any such object must have the _union_ of the properties of `A` and `B`.